# Pygame cannot find desired Font

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
Font = pygame.font.SysFont("SpaceAge", 80)
```

I just install a font, true type font, and want to use it in my game, but pygame cannot find the font and use a base font instead.

Is there anything that I can do to fix this? or to link directly to the font?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed a custom font from website like Dafont, you should use the `pygame.font.Font` pygame class instead (by giving in argument the path of your font file). Maybe your python script do not recognize your newly system font (name is ok ? is it well installed ?).

Comment: I just rechecked the Font, and turned out it is open type font. I checked every thing but it doesn't seems working well. So do I have to link the direct link of my font? 
I tried ```Font = pygame.font.Font("C:/Windows/Fonts/Space Age/Space Age Regular", 80)``` but it returned FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: Try to remove the spaces in "Space Age Regular".

Comment: Isn't the separation character on Windows backslash ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ludovjb's answer, I found if you put the .ttf file in the same directory as the your python file and do this:

```
font = pygame.font.Font("yourfont.tff", 40)
```

It works like a treat!